# Input, Process, and Output pairs of data

Tags: r, data.table

We have a text file that contains drug administration data.  Each line contains a patient ID, an administration date and a drug name, formatted as follows:

```
A234,2014-01-01,5FU
A234,2014-01-02,adderall
B324,1990-06-01,adderall
A234,2014-01-02,tylenol
B324,1990-06-01,tylenol
...etc.
```

Using an input file of this format, produce a list of pairs of drugs that were administered together (i.e. administered to the same patient on the same day) at least twenty-five different times.  In the above sample, adderall and tylenol appear together twice, but every other pair appears only once. Output each qualifying pair as a comma-separated tuple, one per line.

Assuming that the `adderall-tylenol`combination occurred 50 times and `tylenol-5FU` combination occurred 10 times, the output file should look something like this:
           drug_used frequency
    adderall-tylenol        50

Note that because the `tylenol-5FU` combination occurred less than 25 times, it's not included on the final output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `library(data.table)` we can do

```
dt[, paste(drug, collapse = '-'), by = .(id,date)]
#      id       date               V1
# 1: A234 2014-01-01              5FU
# 2: A234 2014-01-02 adderall-tylenol
# 3: B324 1990-06-01 adderall-tylenol
```

Although this also includes id-date combinations where the drug combination is not a tuple.  If you want to only have the lines which have exactly two drugs, then we add a test for this:

```
dt[, if (.N == 2) paste(drug, collapse = '-'), by = .(id,date)]
#      id       date               V1
# 1: A234 2014-01-02 adderall-tylenol
# 2: B324 1990-06-01 adderall-tylenol
```

To further subset these results to only those patients where a drug combination was applied more than 25 times on different days, we can chain the result to another test for this:

```
dt[, if (.N == 2) paste(drug, collapse = '-'), by = .(id,date)][, if (.N>25) .(date,V1), by=id]
```

If you need, you can write these results to a new file using `write.table`

#### The data

```
dt = fread("id, date, drug
A234,2014-01-01,5FU
A234,2014-01-02,adderall
B324,1990-06-01,adderall
A234,2014-01-02,tylenol
B324,1990-06-01,tylenol")
```

Comment: @ProvisionalModulation note that I editted the last part (checking for > 25 times) after you accepted the answer. You should use the code as it is now, in case you did not notice the update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` library to summarize the data table.

```
library(dplyr)

data = data.frame(id = c("A234","A234", "B324", "A234","B324"),
                  date = strptime(c("2014-01-01","2014-01-02", "1990-06-01", "2014-01-02", "1990-06-01"),
                                  format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
                  drug = c("5FU", "adderall", "adderall", "tylenol", "tylenol"))

data %>%
  group_by(id, date) %>%
  summarise(drug_used = paste(drug,collapse = "-"))

Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: id [?]

      id       date        drug_used
  <fctr>     <dttm>            <chr>
1   A234 2014-01-01              5FU
2   A234 2014-01-02 adderall-tylenol
3   B324 1990-06-01 adderall-tylenol
```

Comment: Can the code be adjusted so that the final output contains `drug_used` combinations that occurred 25 times or more? In other words, the original data contains 50 `adderall-tylenol` combinations and 15 `adderall-5FU` combinations, but the final output only contains `adderall-tylenol` combinations.

Comment: Please provide some sample data so that we can reproduce as well as work on your further questions.

Comment: Also, do you mean that you want to have a `drug_used` column to contain combinations that have occurred 25 time or more, and leave other cells NA? Or do you want to add a T/F column to test whether your condition has been met?